# How to cascade 3 dropdown using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu, html-select, cascadingdropdown

How to cascade three dropdown?

I have a page template with three dropdown, the values of option html tags are populate dynamically by mysql. I want to display the options in the 3rd dropdown depends on the 2nd dropdown and it will display the options in the 2nd dropdown depends on the option selected in 1st dropdown.

```
E.g. (1) Job position (2) location (3) a dropdown with "Yes" and "No" option. (Job Position -> Location -> Yes/No (dropdown))
```

I tried some JS scripts but I have no luck to work it correctly. Please help me, I stuck almost 1 week on this :(

PHP snippet:

```
<?php
ob_start();
global $wpdb;

$query_position = "";
$list_position = "";
$result_position = "";
$query_locations = "";
$list_location = "";
$result_location = "";
$query_processed = "";
$list_processed = "";
$result_processed = "";

$query_position = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT position FROM resume_databank ORDER BY position ASC', OBJECT);
$query_locations = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT hiring_location FROM resume_location ORDER BY hiring_location ASC', OBJECT);
$query_processed = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT process_resume FROM resume_databank ORDER BY process_resume ASC', OBJECT);
?>

<div id="">
<form action='' method='post' name='resumeDatabank' id='resumeDatabank'>
<div class="div-select">
<label for="list_position" id="#ddress_search LABEL">Position</label>
<br/>
<select name="list_position" id="filterbypostion">
    <option name="default" class="filter_by" selected="selected" value="Select by Position">Select by Position</option>
    <?php
    foreach($query_position as $option){
        if(isset($_POST['list_position']) && $_POST['list_position'] == $option->position)
            echo '<option name="list_position" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->position .'">'. $option->position .'</option>';
        else
         echo '<option name="list_position" class="filter_by" value="'. $option->position .'">'. $option->position .'</option>';
    };
    ?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="div-select">
<label for="list_location" id="#ddress_search LABEL">Location</label>
<br/>
<select name="list_location" id="filterbylocation">
    <option name="default" class="filter_by" selected="selected" value="Select by Location">Select by Location</option>
    <?php
    foreach($query_locations as $option){
        if(isset($_POST['list_location']) && $_POST['list_location'] == $option->hiring_location)
            echo '<option name="list_location" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->hiring_location .'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
        else
         echo '<option name="list_location" class="filter_by" value="'. $option->hiring_location.'">'. $option->hiring_location .'</option>';
     };
    ?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="div-select">
<label for="list_processed" id="#ddress_search LABEL">Processed</label>
<br/>
<select name="list_processed" id="filterbyprocessed">
    <option name="default" class="filter_by" selected="selected" value="Select by Processed">Select by Processed</option>
    <?php
    foreach($query_processed as $option){
        if(isset($_POST['list_processed']) && $_POST['list_processed'] == $option->processed_option)
            echo '<option name="list_processed" class="filter_by" selected value="'. $option->processed_option .'">'. $option->processed_option .'</option>';
        else
         echo '<option name="list_processed" class="filter_by" value="'. $option->processed_option.'">'. $option->processed_option .'</option>';
     };
    ?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="div-input">
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="div-input-submit"/>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my sample (adapt it for your example), I hope to help:

```
<?
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('test');
if(!empty($_POST['location'])) {
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM location");
echo '<select id="location">';
while($rw = mysql_fetch_row($qry)) {
echo '<option value="'.$rw[1].'">'.$rw[1].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
} else {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job");
echo '<select id="job">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)) {
echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[1].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#job").bind("change", function(){
$.post("index.php",{'location': $('#job').val()},function(data){
$('#location').remove();
$("#job").after(data);
});
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: what if the js script and the php is on the same file? how to load it here `$("#location").load("rpc.php");`?

Comment: but the js and php are in the same page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112662/discussion-between-user014019-and-edd).